# jinja2: Split variable into array and print in loop

Tags: jinja2

Right now 'line' variable contains this text. 
**[Use the respective Hyperlink based on the OTTP part of the configuration]         Data OTTP 8.4 Documentation        Data OTP 9.7 Documentation**

I would like to split this and print in loops like this

```
   [Use the respective Hyperlink based on the OTTP part of the
    configuration] 
   Data OTTP 8.4 Documentation 
   Data OTP 9.7 Documentation
```

Tried this code but getting error "line is undefined"  error.

```
{% set list1 = line.split('       ') %}
{%p for list1 in documentation_on_now %}
{{list1}}
{%p endfor %}
```

Comment: There is no display difference between your two example lines. You have to format them using code blocks if you want people to understand what you want to acheive.

Comment: you are right.  I wanted expected line to be on new lines. Is there any way I can  edit it ?

Comment: You mean like by clicking the edit link right below your question ? :)

Comment: How are you setting the `line` variable? It's not evident from your question.